# Cannot cut & paste between a Linux host and a Linux VMware Workstation Guest

Tags: linux, vmware

I am running Fedora 35 as my host / laptop. Installed VMware Workstation 16 pro, it works, I installed a Fedora 35 guest / VM but cannot get it to let me cut *& paste between host & guest.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask .. I'd use SuperUser for this question.  BUT  -- You need VM tools installed on the guest and to enable copy/paste in the VM settings.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to install VMWare tools on your VM. This will be needed to enable the copy paste functionality in any VM you create in VMWare Workstation.

This link might help you out : https://www.isumsoft.com/computer/2-ways-enable-copy-paste-work-in-vmware.html